# I want to receive multiple data from arduino to raspberry pi using I2C

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

Thank you to whoever is kind enough to look into this question.

I want to receive multiple data from arduino to raspberry pi using I2C.

I can obtain 1 data from arduino, but once I move to more than one data, it fails to do so.

I have tried multiple methods so far, and I found this method to work the best to obtain data from Arduino.

My previous attempt in obtaining data from arduino is as follows:
[I want to read from Arduino using I2C using Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254685/i-want-to-read-from-arduino-using-i2c-using-raspberry-pi)
[Raspberry Pi's terminal response has weird font that cannot be recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255579/raspberry-pis-terminal-response-has-weird-font-that-cannot-be-recognized)

Which are all solved by now.
Got Massive Help from link below
https://area-51.blog/2014/02/15/connecting-an-arduino-to-a-raspberry-pi-using-i2c/

Arduino Code

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define echoPin 7
#define trigPin 8

int number=0;
long duration;
long distance;

void setup()
{
  //Join I2C bus as slave with address 8
  Wire.begin(8);

  //Call SendData & Receive Data
  Wire.onRequest(SendData);
  //Setup pins as output and input to operate ultrasonic sensor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(echoPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop ()
{
  digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(trigPin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);

  duration=pulseIn(echoPin,HIGH);

  distance=duration/58.2;

  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println(" cm");
}

void SendData()
{
  Wire.write(distance);
  Wire.write("Why No Work?");
  Wire.write(distance);
}
```

C++ Code

```
//Declare and Include the necessary header files
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//Define Address of Slave Address
#define ADDRESS 0x08

//Eliminate the Used of std in the future
using namespace std;

static const char *devName="/dev/i2c-1";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Check to see if C++ works
    cout<<"Hello, World!\n";
    cout<<"I2C: Connecting"<<endl;
    int file;

    if ((file = open(devName, O_RDWR))<0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "I2C: Failed to access");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, ADDRESS)<0)
    {
        cout<<"Failed to Access"<<endl;
    }
    char buf[0];
    char dd;
    for (int i=0; i<100;i++)
    {
        read(file,buf, 3);
        float distance= (int) buf[0];
        dd= buf[1];
        float dist=(int) buf[2];

        cout<<distance<<endl;
        usleep(10000);
        cout<<"doh"<<endl;
        cout<<dd<<endl;
        cout<<dist<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I would expect from the c++ code would be as follows

```
15
doh
Why No Work?
15
```

But I get

```
15
doh
weird font can't be recognized
255
```

Comment: `char buf[0];` – array of length 0??? In consequence, `read(file, buf, 3)` pretty sure will invoke undefined behaviour, and all of `buf[0]`, `buf[1]`, `buf[2]` are invalid, too

Answer (score 2):

```
Wire.write(distance);
```

wants to write a `long` onto the I2C bus. For an Arduino This is 32 bits, 4 bytes, of data. I'm not sure exactly what `wire.write` does because the documentation I can find is substandard to the point of being garbage, but [the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireWrite) looks like it's going to send exactly 1 of the 4 bytes you wanted to send. In order to send more than one byte, it looks like you need to use the array version: `Wire.write(&distance, sizeof (distance));`, but even this may not be sufficient. I'll get back into that later.

```
Wire.write("Why No Work?");
```

writes a null-terminated string (specifically a `const char[13]`) onto the I2C bus. I don't know arduino well enough to know if this also sends the terminating null.

so

```
Wire.write(distance);
Wire.write("Why No Work?");
Wire.write(distance);
```

needed to write at least 4 + 12 + 4 bytes onto the I2C bus. and probably only wrote 1 + 12 + 1.

On the Pi side,

```
read(file,buf, 3);
```

read out 3 bytes. This isn't enough to get the whole of `distance`, let alone the array of characters and second write of `distance`. You need to read all of the data you wrote, at least 20 bytes.

In addition,

```
char buf[0];
```

defines an array of 0 length. There isn't much you can do with it as there is no space to store anything here. It cannot hold 3 characters, let alone the 20 or 21 necessary. `read` of 3 bytes wrote into invalid memory and the program [can no longer be counted on for sane results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This means that at best

```
    float distance= (int) buf[0];
    dd= buf[1];
    float dist=(int) buf[2];
```

got only one byte of the four bytes of `distance` and it's dumb luck that the result was the same as expected. `dd` got exactly one character, not the whole string, and this is turning out to be nonsense because of one of the preceding mistakes. `dist` is similarly garbage.

To successfully move data from one machine to another, you need to establish a communication protocol. You can't just write a `long` onto a wire. `long` doesn't have the same size on all platforms, nor does it always have the [same encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). You have to make absolutely certain that both sides agree on how the `long` is to be written (size  and byte order) and read.

Exactly how you are going to do this is up to you, but [here are some pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810235/4581301) and a search term, **serialization**, to assist you in further research.